# Joining a table to a substring in SQL

Tags: sql

I am having an issue on joining a table to a result in a substring in SQL.

Here is my statement:

```
SELECT a.MEASR_COMP_ID
     , f.D1_USAGE_ID
     , f.SCH_SELECTION_DT
     , g.MEASR_COMP_ID
     , g.MSRMT_VAL
     , i.USAGE_ID
     , SUBSTR(dbms_lob.substr(i.USG_DATA_AREA, 4000, 1)
              ,INSTR(dbms_lob.substr(i.USG_DATA_AREA, 4000, 1)
              ,'<startReading>') + LENGTH('<startReading>'), 8)
             "Start Reading"
     , SUBSTR(dbms_lob.substr(i.USG_DATA_AREA, 4000, 1)
     , INSTR(dbms_lob.substr(i.USG_DATA_AREA, 4000, 1)
     , '<endReading>') + LENGTH('<endReading>'), 8) as "End Reading"
FROM C1_USAGE I
   , CISADM.D1_USAGE@CCBMDM f
   , CISADM.D1_MSRMT@CCBMDM g
   , CISADM.D1_USAGE_PERIOD_SQ@CCBMDM a
WHERE f.USG_EXT_ID = i.USAGE_ID AND
      f.D1_USAGE_ID = a.D1_USAGE_ID AND
      a.MEASR_COMP_ID = g.MEASR_COMP_ID AND
      i.USAGE_ID = '119993413555' AND
      SUBSTR(dbms_lob.substr(i.USG_DATA_AREA, 4000, 1)
             ,INSTR(dbms_lob.substr(i.USG_DATA_AREA, 4000
             ,1), '<endReading>') + LENGTH('<endReading>'), 8)
             as "End Reading" = g.MSRMT.VAL
```

Comment: What's the issue?  Did you get any error messages?  What results did you get?  What results do you expect?

Comment: Suggest that you use modern, explicit join syntax, rather than older implicit joins.  That may solve whatever problem you are facing.

Comment: Alias' don't belong in the `Where` clause. As Rahul states below.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using?

Comment: I am getting this error on the last line of code:    ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 18 Column: 151

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine except that you should remove the part `as "End Reading"` from your condition and also consider using proper ANSI style `JOIN` syntax rather this puzzled syntax